# Check if a certain number exists in a database using python and add 1 to a variable

Tags: python, database, variables, if-statement, increment

I am trying to check if a certain number exists in a database using `python`.

When it detects the number I am looking for, then I want it to do `variable += 1`. I do not have any specific code, but here is some example code of what I want it to do.

```
import pyodbc 

one = 0

conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DSN=MACCD')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT first,second,third,fourth,fifth FROM ExampDatabase')

if "1 is detected in the database":
    one += 1
print(one)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific with your SQL statement? How many rows and fields will it return? Maybe you can even post the actual SQL query you intend to run.

Comment: if your asking how many rows it returns the answer is 1473 rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the [`pyodbc` docs](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Getting-started#select-basics), you could try this:

```
import pyodbc 

conn = pyodbc.connect(...)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(...)

# whatever number you are looking for
my_target = ...
target_counter = 0

row_counter = 0
while True:
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    if row is None:
        break

    row_counter += 1
    print(row_counter, row)

    if my_target in row:
        target_counter += 1

print('rows returned:', row_counter)
print('targets found:', target_counter)
```